# How can i mock a return type of a factory method of a 3rd party library?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq, assemblies, mono.cecil

I am working on a tool that loads assemblies using Mono.Cecil. I have the following Factory that returns an object named binary and depends on interface responsible for loading assemblies with `AssemblyDefinintion.ReadAssembly` method.

I am completely new to unit testing and I need to unit test the `GetBinary` method.

```cs
internal sealed class DotNetBinaryFactory : IBinaryFactory
{
    private readonly IBinaryLoader binaryLoader;
    public DotNetBinaryFactory(IBinaryLoader binaryLoader)
    {
        this.binaryLoader = binaryLoader;
    }

    [NotNull] public Binary GetBinary([NotNull] FilePath path)
    {
        var assembly = binaryLoader.LoadBinary(path);
        return BinaryUtils.GetBinary(assembly);
    }
}
```

Here is the `IBinaryLoader` dependency implementation

```cs
internal interface IBinaryLoader
{
    AssemblyDefinition LoadBinary(FilePath path);
}

internal sealed class DotnetBinaryLoader : IBinaryLoader
{
    public AssemblyDefinition LoadBinary([NotNull] FilePath path)
    {
        try
        {
            return AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path.Path);
        }                
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in loading Assembly From : " + path.Path);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So to unit test `GetBinary` method I need to mock `IBinaryLoader` and setup `LoadBinary` method to return a dummy `AssemblyDefinition` object, but I can't create one.

Here is what I tried

```cs
[Test]
public void GetDotnetBinary_AssemblyDefinitionInput_ReturnCorrectDotnetFrameworkBianry()
{
    var path = FilePath.GetRandom();
    var mockedAssemblyDef = new Mock<AssemblyDefinition>();
    var binaryLoader = new Mock<IBinaryLoader>();
    binaryLoader.Setup(m => m.LoadBinary(path)).Returns(mockedAssemblyDef.Object);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create mocks of services, not of data. In your case `AssemblyDefinition` is data, and is `sealed` as well. Mocks aren't meant for concrete data classes. Your mock of the "service" `binaryLoader` looks ok.

What you need to do instead is create your dummy `AssemblyDefinition` another way, and return that. I'm not familiar with Mono.Cecil, but it looks like there is a static [Create()](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyDefinition.cs) method you could use. Once you've got that instance you need, the rest of your test should fall into place.

You'll end up with something like

```
[Test]
public void GetDotnetBinary_AssemblyDefinitionInput_ReturnCorrectDotnetFrameworkBianry()
{
    // arrange
    var path = FilePath.GetRandom();
    var assemblyDef = AssemblyDefinition.Create(...); // or however your create a real one
    var binaryLoader = new Mock<IBinaryLoader>();
    binaryLoader.Setup(m => m.LoadBinary(path)).Returns(assemblyDef);
    var factory = new DotNetBinaryFactory(binaryLoader);

    // act
    var result = factory.GetBinary(path);

    // assert
    // your assertions here...
}
```

I see also that your types are internal. Assuming your tests are in a different assembly, you will have to make the internals visible to that assembly. This is done by putting an [[InternalsVisibleTo]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netstandard-2.1) attribute in the source assembly.